# Most Important Features for a CMS

Tags: content-management-system

Suppose someone is building you a CMS (Content Management System) from scratch.  What are the most important features to include and why?

Answer (score 29):

- security - [OWASP Top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007)
- user management & user roles
- action and view permissions
- content versioning and audit
- some form of workflow and notifications
- i18n support on literals and object versions
- normalized database schema design
- some form of content import-export
- assets management and thumbnail generation for uploads
- Valid XHTML (compressed with GZIP)
- Rich text editing (e.g FCKeditor) which generates accessible markup
- Valid and minified CSS and javascript (e.g using YUI)
- automatically generated sitemaps.org document
- integration with Google Analytics
- automatic RSS feeds
- open search support
- print css and/or print versions of content
- SEO consideration for duplicate content (e.g use of canonical tag)

Answer (score 17):

I think from a developer's perspective it would be an **open modular architecture**. IMHO there are always things to add which the CMS platform isn't providing out of the box. Also, it should be **database-based**.

**Existing modules** should cover the most important tasks: news, contacts, documents, forums, shop, survey, events, image gallery, navigation, links, fulltext-search, login, newsletter, etc.

From the user's perspective I think that the **content editor** ([WYSIWYG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wysiwyg)) is the most important piece. The ability to edit inside the "live" page is a great feature. Upload of images with automated resizing and the upload of files should be easy.

The existence of page/control and website **templates** is also very helpful when you're starting with a CMS. **Versioning** of documents/pages is also a often required feature and a **work-flow engine**, where there are authors who create content and editors who are allowed to unlock it.

**RSS syndication** is another important feature that should be available in a modern CMS.

For international site it very important that the CMS had some sort of built-in **multi-lingual support**.

Then I think a good CMS nowadays must provide tools for Search Enginge Optimization, e.g. there must be a way to define and insert **search engine friendly URLs**.

Answer (score 4):

Not mentioned already: A CMS system should easily integrate into an existing software infrastucture, so interoparability is a strong requirement.

Example: If your CMS supported [WebDav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), you win Microsoft Office as editing tools without any extra expenses.

Answer (score 4):

My number one requirement when choosing a CMS system is the ability to skin it easily and control the markup.

Users can be really fussy about getting the layout EXACTLY as they want.

Answer (score 3):

1) WYSIWYG editor.  Being able to edit HTML content as if it were in Microsoft Word.  That includs the ability to upload your own images.

2) Creating new pages without query strings ie) not 'pages.aspx?pageid=5' but 'contact.aspx'

3) Additional features such as news, photo gallery, blog, user management, etc...

Personally I really like the [CMS starter kit](http://www.codeplex.com/MyWebPagesStarterKit) Microsoft has available on codeplex.  It is very well done and uses XML file storage so it *doesn't need a database*!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the things that others have mentioned:

**Caching**

If you page comprises lots of "pieces" - e.g.  a Banner pane, Left pane, Main pane, Right pane and Footer pane, and perhaps each of those will have multiple "widgets" in them, then the effort of constructing the page becomes significant (both in database calls, and in rendering at the web server).  Having some intelligent caching that is able to detect when any of the underlying content blocks has changed will make a big different to performance

[CMS Matrix](http://cmsmatrix.org/) may be a useful comparison resource of existing CMS products

Answer (score 2):

The features you need the most will naturally depend on how the CMS is going to be used, and by whom. For some, licensing will be the greatest issue, while for others, some obscure requirement like support for TIFF files could be the thing.

If you want en extensive list of CMS features, take a look at [CMS Feature Lists](http://www.cmsreview.com/Features/Lists.html)

Answer (score 0):

When working with clients, I often heard a number of requirements that, in my opinion, had little to do with what a modern CMS really needs. Far too often emphasis was on features that should have been in the domain of template designers, such as support for responsive design (whatever that really means), the ability to add brand elements etc.

I compiled a list of the top 5 features a modern CMS needs at http://www.simoahava.com/content-management/modern-cms-top-5-features/

Modular architecture and strong security are the most important features from a technical standpoint. Complete control over content, source code and the software solution itself are all huge perks for any CMS.

Simo Ahava