# Feature set of a CMS and frameworks

Tags: java, content-management-system

Most people have heard of Content Management Systems. However, what basic features should an application contain so it can be considered as a true CMS? Also, what Java frameworks could be used to make one?

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380259/most-important-features-for-a-cms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are main features of a CMS:

- Allow for a large number of people to contribute to and share stored data
- Control access to data, based on user roles. User roles define what information each user can view or edit
- Aid in easy storage and retrieval of data
- Reduce repetitive duplicate input
- Improve the ease of report writing
- Improve communication between users

> what Java frameworks could be used to
>   make one?

**[See this for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)**

Answer (score 0):

The most important feature of a CMS is to enable users from all over the place to log in and create/share information. Usually a CMS is a web application like Drupal and Joomla, but it's not restricted as such. If you want to use Java, I'd recommend Google's [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). You code in Java and 'compile' it to Javascript.

Comment: GWT is a development toolkit for Java professionals to build desktop-like applications. How do you consider that a CMS ???

Comment: @Philippe Ya I know what GWT is. It can be used as a framework to build a CMS, which was also one of the things the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Osmek](http://osmek.com) would be good solution as well.  All you would have to do is write a java integration class.