# Create Content Management System (CMS) in grails

Tags: grails, content-management-system

I'm an intermediate user in grails and I want to create a **Content Management System** and an end user application in grails. It mainly involves video uploading and downloading in cloud servers.

I seen the [Most Important features for cms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380259/most-important-features-for-a-cms/)

Can any one suggest about architecture and how it can be easily implement in grails?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Except if you want to do it _just for learning_, I highly recommend trying out [the existing applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems). A decent CMS requires tons of work.

Comment: I suggest using the already built oss grails cms www.weceem.org

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @elias that a CMS needs tons of work.
As to your question, I suggest you use an existing one, just like @mostkiteau has mentioned, or go to http://grails.org/plugins/search?q=cms for more CMS plugins for Grails.